# Maximal size of an almost-disjoint linearly independent family in $K^{\mathbb{N}}$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, combinatorics, additive-combinatorics, infinitary-combinatorics

Let $K$ be a field, say infinite, and denote by $L$ the $K$-vector space $K^{\mathbb{N}}$. What is the maximal cardinality of a $K$-linearly independent subset $X$ of $L$ such that any two distinct elements of $X$ agree on at most finitely many elements of $\mathbb{N}$? Is it $|K|^{\aleph_0}$?

Note that by Erdos-Kaplansky theorem, the linear dimension of $L$ is $|K|^{\aleph_0}$.

Comment: Cross posted from MO: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/139595/maximal-size-of-an-almost-disjoint-linearly-independent-family-in-k-mathbbn